# Make list of X and Y coordinates

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
Filedata:
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 100]
[3, 0, 0, 200]
[4, 100, 0, 0]
[5, 100, 0, 100]
[6, 100, 0, 200]
...
```

where the first column is an ID, the second is the X coordinate, the third the Y coordinate and the fourth the Z coordinate.

I'd like to make two lists of the different X and Y coordinates in the original list:

```
X:
[0, 100, ...]
Y:
[0, 100, ...]
```

to do this I thought of a code but in the process I realised there must be an easier why of doing this instead of doing multiple for and if loops. Any ideas?

Comment: `filedata` is a list of lists or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IDs,Xs,Ys,Zs = zip(*filedata)
positions = zip(Xs,Ys,Zs) # list of tuples of (x,y,z) 

unique_Xs = []
[unique_Xs.append(val) for val in Xs if val not in unique_Xs]

unique_Ys = []
[unique_Ys.append(val) for val in Ys if val not in unique_Ys]
```

I think would work , assuming filedata is a 2d list, although filedata is not a great variable name ...

I added a way to get unique points in each list ... not entirely sure thats what you want though

Comment: In order to have a list for X I could use: `X=positions[0:]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
filedata = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 0, 100],
    [3, 0, 0, 200],
    [4, 100, 0, 0],
    [5, 100, 0, 100],
    [6, 100, 0, 200],
]

IDs, Xs, Ys, Zs = zip(*filedata)
Xs, Ys, Zs = set(Xs), set(Ys), set(Zs)
print 'X:', Xs
print 'Y:', Ys
print 'Z:', Zs
```

Comment: +1 for adding the set part to it ... assuming he wants only unique points in his list(and that list order is not important) ... recall that `set((0,100)) == set((100,0))`

Comment: @JoranBeasley good point. For me `(0,100)) != (100,0)`. But I prefer having different lists for X and Y.

Comment: @jpcgandre if you only want unique results, but in list format and sorted, you can use list(sorted(set(Xs)))

Comment: not sorted by value ... but sorted by order in original list I think

Comment: @JoranBeasley in that case your answer is the one to go with

Answer (score 0):

It seems OP only wants lists of X's and Y's. He can do something like this:

```
xs=zip(*filedata)[1]
ys=zip(*filedata)[2]
```

Comment: Yes, but a list with only the different X's, Y's

Comment: that is more expensive than getting all of them and only using xs and ys ... I removed my negative vote(since this does answer the question). .. but this is not an efficient solution

Comment: @JoranBeasley You're right. This is twice expensive and I oddly overlookeded it.